# How to exclude action methods from validation in struts2

Tags: struts2

My Action class have the following methods,

```
1.add
2.edit
3.loadEdit
4.remove
5.list
6.execute
```

in this i need to apply validation for add and edit..how do need to config in struts.xml.I followed,

```
<action name="editComment" method="edit"
        class="com.mmm.ehspreg2.web.action.product.CommentAction">
    <result name="success">/jsp/propertyManager/loadList.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="removeComment" method="remove"
        class="com.mmm.ehspreg2.web.action.product.CommentAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
        <param name="excludeMethods">remove</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <result type="tiles">listComment</result>
    <result type="tiles" name="input">listComment</result>
</action>
```

When I configure it like this, remove action method is not getting called. I don't understand the problem. Please assist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply list all the methods you **don't** want to be run through the validation framework in the excludeMethods parameter.  Since you only want `add` and `edit` validated, list the other 4 as follows:

```
<interceptor-ref name="validation">
    <param name="excludeMethods">loadEdit,remove,list,execute</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

You can read more about it in the [Validation Interceptor docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/validation-interceptor.html).

Comment: It is not working. I have different actions for every methods.do i need to specify this excludethods configuration in all actions?

Comment: No, you can define your own defaultStack at the top of your struts.xml.  If you look on this page for "defaultStack" you'll see what is currently being run.  Copy it into your own config and change what you need:  http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/struts-defaultxml.html

Answer (score 10):

you can also use @SkipValidation before method initialization in action class

e.g.

```
@SkipValidation
public String save() {
    String result = super.save();
    if (result.equals(SAVE)) {
        setMessage1(getText("save.successful"));
    } else {
        setMessage1(getText("save.unsuccessful"));
    }
    jsonResponse = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    jsonResponse.put(FIELD_JSONRESPONSE_STATUS,
            KEY_JSONRESPONSE_MESSAGE_SUCCESS);
    jsonResponse.put(FIELD_JSONRESPONSE_MESSAGE,
            KEY_JSONRESPONSE_EMPTY_STRING);
    jsonResponse.put(FIELD_JSONRESPONSE_VALUE, domainModel.getId());
    // System.out.println("domainModel>>>>>>" + domainModel.getId());
    return result;
}
```